# VB.net PrintForm Not Working in New Thread

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a e-filing app and I need to print an adhesive label with some info to attach to the physical folder.

I already designed the label as a Form put the logo and everything that I need there.  Then on the Form.Shown event I put the command to print:

Me.PrintLabelForm.Print()   (This is VisualStudio PowerPack Control)

And here is where I bump into a problem.  The print out is totally empty (I already changed margins setup the printer, etc). The issue is that the form is not actually fully loaded, I switch the method to the print preview and the controls are there but they are empty.

I tried several approaches but I have been not able to do this automatically.  One solution that I found was to have a button to do the Me.PrintLabelForm.Print() then it works because the form is already fully loaded and displayed but this is not an option.  I need the form to open automatically, print and close.

An option that I think it should work will be to have a new thread with a timer then printing so I did this:

```
Private Sub LabelPrint_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub LabelPrint_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0.1
    PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0.1
    PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0.1
    PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0.1
    PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True

    Dim PrintThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf PrintSub)
    PrintThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PrintSub()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Me.PrintLabelForm.Print()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

The idea was to have the PrintSub to give the app enough time to finish to render the whole thing then print but I am getting this error:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.dll

Additional information: The window being printed must be visible and contain focus.**

So I wonder how to make this thread have the window form in focus in order to be able to print.

That is all. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: How are the form elements being populated in this form?

Comment: I put the elements in the design view.  It contains a PictureBox and 4 Labels.  The picture box has the image already assigned and it does not change.
The process is: When in the main form a button is pressed the label text will change then this form will be shown, print and close all by itself no user interaction.

Comment: Simple solution, do not use that PowerPack stuff and do it properly using the [PrintDocument Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

Comment: @AlvaroBuenaventura - Yes, but how are the form elements populated?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance Enigmativity but I don't understand the question of how are the forms elements populated.

Comment: @AlvaroBuenaventura - Once the form loads it should show all of the controls and their data - it should be fully populated. But you're saying it isn't. So I'm wondering how the form is populated? Does it do some sort of web service call after the form is loaded, etc?

Comment: Ok got it. No, the PictureBox has a .jpg file on my computer. The 4 Labels get text from the form that load this one. The code is: LabelPrint.Label.Text="XXXXXX", the same for the other 3 then  LabelPrint.Show().  Actually after a lot of testing that I did yesterday, It looks like the standard PrintForm() method was the one making the controls to be created but not fully drawn.  If you check the Question Code vs the Answer the difference that solved everything was to add  (Me, PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly) to the PrintForm command. If in the answer you remove it,you will see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Always work with the form only from main thread.

You found it right – form printing will not run from new thread.

When you do any actions on forms, you must perform all the work from Dispatcher thread. It is the thread on which all event methods run. If you fail doing so, you can encounter many side effects. (Not only problem with printing. I've been there and this advice from senior Windows programmer helped me to get things back to normal.) So **do not use form printing from any other thread.**

If you want a workaround for this, print form to the image (in main thread) and then you can print the image using new thread.

This has nothing to do with .NET, this is related to internals of Windows Forms technology. Welcome to Windows programming.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wish to have an event "TheFormIsFullyLoadedAndFullyDisplayed".  I guess I will have to put a MsgBox in the Shown Event before PrintForm so it delays the PrintForm and gives time for the Form to be fully loaded.

Comment: The changes the way I was used to code (Back in the days of DOS and Using QBasic then use Basic to compile) and Micro-controller Programming where everything is linear and using Interruptions to call events (Such good old days) jajajaja.

Comment: @AlvaroBuenaventura – maybe you do not need to change your approach globally. My answer is valid only for Windows Forms technology. I am not sure how this works with newer windowing technology – WPF. Your attempt to use another thread is generally fine, but this time you were working directly with the form, and that thing is restricted.

Comment: @AlvaroBuenaventura – you can always display another form "Please wait..." when creating your printing form and hide it upon showing the printing form. Or you can paint all of your output directly to the image (not to form) and this way you can do all printing work in new thread. Also examine PrintDocument class as stated in comment below the question. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it putting this line in the Form.Shown

```
PrintLabelForm.Print(Me, PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly)
```

I don't know why or how but it works.

Thanks to all of you guys for your help.  Let's hope I don't find myself trying to do stuff when the form is fully displayed.

This is my full code let's hope it works for someone else:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing

Public Class PrintAdhesiveLabel

    Private Sub LabelPrint_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub LabelPrint_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = 0.1
        PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right = 0.1
        PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = 0.1
        PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom = 0.1
        PrintLabelForm.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        PrintLabelForm.Print(Me, PrintForm.PrintOption.ClientAreaOnly)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918024.aspx) is relevant:

> Only the form that currently has focus can be printed by using this
>   method. If you have set the Form property to another form before
>   calling this method, the image of the form may not be rendered as
>   expected. To avoid this, call the Focus method of the form before you
>   call Print.

So call `Me.PrintLabelForm.Focus()` before calling `Me.PrintLabelForm.Print()`:

```vb
Private Sub PrintSub()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Me.PrintLabelForm.Focus()
    Me.PrintLabelForm.Print()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but sadly it gives me a syntax error. "Focus is not a member of PrintForm".